# Looking for open orders in a certain level

Tags: pine-script

I'm looking for a way by which I can check if there is an order at a certain level in pine-script. For example, assume that I want to put a buy stop at 300.00, so I'm looking for a way to check if there is a buy stop at this level to prevent two buy stops in the level. Please help me solve the problem.
Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

The example for next thoughts:

```
...
someLevel = highest(high, 10)
strategy.entry(str.format("buy level {0}", someLevel), true, stop = someLevel)
...
```